# Flat nilpotent ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, nilpotence, flatness

> Can a non-Noetherian commutative ring have a nonzero flat nilpotent ideal?

Any such ideal would have to be "tensor-nilpotent" as defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299941/tensor-nilpotent-modules) for the same exponent that it is nilpotent. Also, no nonzero flat nilpotent ideal can exist in any *Noetherian* commutative ring, because any tensor power of a nonzero finitely generated module (e.g. a nonzero finitely generated ideal) must itself be nonzero. In particular, $p\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z}$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n \ge 2$, is not a flat $\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z}$-module.